How to mark an *instance* of a Python class as deprecated?
I have inherited the maintenance on some API code. One of the things I need to update is some environment information (think staging, production). The old names were test and production, while the new names are sandbox, simulator and production. The old name test has the same semantics as simulator today.
How this was implemented is using a class, with instances predefined for each environment, something like:
class Environment(object):
    def __init__(self, name, params):
        self.name = name
        self.params = params

test = Environment('test', ... params ...)
production = Environment('production', ... params ...)

I can easily define the new names, and to not break existing code, do
test = simulator

But I'd like to have code which uses the old instance test raise a Python deprecation warning.
How can I do it? I can hack it by inserting an if inside the class code and raise a deprecation warning there, but is there a cleaner way?

This is weird design, assigning instances of a class to the class itself. There's gotta be a better way to do that - not that I know how based on this brief example. I suppose the core problem is that the class isn't self-contained. I might break up the name Environment into 1) the class, 2) a namespace that contains the instances.

@Colin'tHart What they're saying is that there's nothing deprecated about the instances themselves but the names (attributes) by which they're accessed. The opposite side of the coin you mention is that you'd still have the same problem if they weren't instances; how they're accessed seems like the more central part of the question.

You could always ask a new question instead of pulling this one out from under the answer...

It's at least not obvious how the linked duplicate would apply to this particular problem (deprecating an attribute, rather than an entire function or class). (Oh, I missed the edit. Yes, that changes the question entirely.)

@CrazyChucky The question was closed as duplicate anyway... which always happens on SO. The whole model is so insanely broken. How it should work is to leave all questions open and have them point at a definitive wiki of resources. And also allow forum style threads, again with links to a wiki-like resource. Nobody can ask the perfect question, and it goes into a different direction and/or gets closed before it can be edited to be the perfect question. /rant.

Could you include the definitions of the new names, to make it clear? Ideally, provide a [mre].

Reopened. The main question at the link is "why is there no standard library decorator for this (common) task?", which is more of a design choice question, not a how-to question. Although, I'm sure some info there is applicable here.

@Colin I would say SO is supposed to be that "wiki-like resource". Asking a good question takes a lot of effort. If you want a forum, there are other places for that, like Reddit or SO Discussions. That said, if you're upset with over-eager closing, I get where you're coming from.

Would it be a problem to have a duplicate instance? That is, a separate instantiation for test and simulator? Or do they track state in such a way that they need to be references to the same object?

I think a duplicate instance will work. There's no state tracked in the class code at least. I'm fairly certain it's only used to store parameters necessary for the API to connect to the different environments.

I think I have a reasonable answer. Would you consider rolling this question back and asking another (linked here) so that I can post it there?

A class-level property (combining property and classmethod) would work, but those are deprecated.
Instead, you need to provide a custom metaclass so that you can convert the class attribute Test to a property defined on the metaclass. The property getter can then raise the deprecation warning before returning the replacement value.
import warnings


class Foo(type):
    @property
    def Test(self):
        warnings.warn('"Test" is deprecated, use "Simulator" instead', DeprecationWarning)
        return self.Simulator


class Environment(metaclass=Foo):
    def __init__(self, name, params):
        self.name = name
        self.params = params


Environment.Simulator = Environment('test', [])
Environment.Production = Environment('production', [])

print(Environment.Test.name)

outputs
/Users/chepner/tmp.py:7: DeprecationWarning: "Test" is deprecated, use "Simulator" instead
  warnings.warn('"Test" is deprecated, use "Simulator" instead', DeprecationWarning)
test
 

